# AWS Directory Service

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-directory-service

I got couple of .net web applications installed on the EC2 instance on the AWS cloud. Have one requirement to implement the single sign on using the AWS directory service(AWS Microsopft AD). I do have the AWS Microsoft AD in place.

Now the questions are

1. Cannot see any place from I can create the users and manage the group for the AD. (documentation are saying i need to have another ec2 instance with active directory installed and connect to AWS AD as a client). is there any simple way to do this.
2. For Adding the .net application for SSO i need to add application in the Amazon workspace application manager and create the package etc. which is kind of complicated. Do we have a simple way to just add the application like we can do in the Azure AD service.
   Any Pointer and documentation is appreciated.